# On Impossible events

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Let's consider a continuous random variable $X$ distributed according to a PDF $p(x):\mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

Is there a meaningful sense in which one could say that for any $x_0:p(x_0)=0$ the event $X=x_0$ is impossible? By impossible, I mean that if we simulate $X$ then we never observe in the sample the value $x_0$.

If the answer is no, how do we make sure that $X$  will never get the value $x_0$?

Note that my question is not about the well-known fact that any event of the form $X=x_0$ is almost impossible, in the sense that $\mathbb{P}(X=x_0)=0$, and this does not mean that such events cannot happen (i.e., if we simulate $X$ then we can observe the value $x_0$ in the sample).

Comment: You seem to be making unmentioned assumptions about the probability p, which you have not defined. Also you seem to be not distinguishing between a) something's never happening and b) its having probability zero — often two different things.

Comment: In real life, probability zero events are never observed. You may be thinking of such idealizations as an infinite sequence of coin tosses or an infinitely precise measurement, but such things don't exist in the real world. When you say "if we simulate $X$ then we can observe the value $x_0$ in the sample" I guess you're thinking of a discrete approximation to a continuous variable $X$.

Comment: If you're thinking of a continuous variable, like a normal distribution of grades, you could very well say any individual grade (considered as a real number) is probability zero.  i.e. from a certain point of view, probability zero events are the only things that occur.  But this isn't the most productive point of view.

Comment: There isn’t really a mathematically rigorous definition of an event being impossible that matches our intuition. You could make a case, for example, that if your PDF has an isolated zero then that zero isn’t really “impossible”, whatever that means. Maybe if the PDF is zero in a neighborhood of $x_0$ then you could say it’s “impossible”? But this is really more of an opinion thing than anything else.

Comment: Well, you cannot exactly simulate from a continuous distribution anyway, in a computer with finite storage and finite time. This holds even if the density is nowhere zero, say, the standard normal distribution: your simulated values will be in some finite set, whether that is IEEE floating point, or something else.

Comment: But, admitting an approximate simulation, like we really do in computers, it is a valid concern that you might not want positive probability for obtaining values where the true density is zero. I think the canonical example is simulating from the uniform distribution over the *open* interval $(0,1)$, or the half-open interval $[0,1)$. Actual pseudorandom generators do take this into account. (I might write an answer to this -- unless the question is closed, which seems to be happening.)

Comment: I have voted to reopen: If understood in the numerical simulation context, the question expresses a valid concern (for research even), even though the answer is relatively easy. I have an answer that this margin is too narrow to support.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen I've just cast the fifth vote to reopen.

Comment: @Yemon Thanks. I hope we are not going to see trigger-happy "moderator action".

Comment: There is an interesting essay by Littlewood about how probability theory can never apply to the real world...  found in *Littlewood's Miscellany*

Comment: "In real life, probability zero events are never observed" makes no sense, because probability does not attach to real-world events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good question about practical simulation, but it needs
a bit of reinterpretation.  This is what I understand to be
the question(s):

> Q1. What is **meant** by saying that we are sampling finitely represented numbers (e.g. IEEE floating point) from a continuous distribution, given by a density function which is zero at some points?  For example, sampling from the uniform distribution over the closed interval $[0,1]$ or the open interval $(0,1)$.
>
> Q2: How is the intended sampling **achieved** in practice?

For starters, recall that you cannot exactly simulate from a
continuous distribution anyway, in a computer with bounded storage and
bounded time. This holds even if the density is nowhere zero, say, the
standard normal distribution: your simulated values will be in some
finite set, whether that is IEEE floating point, or something else.

So there are in fact two (related) distributions here: The underlying continuous distribution, and the discrete *sampling distribution* of
the values that you are really receiving.

## Answer to Q1

The canonical example is simulating from the uniform distribution over
the open interval $(0,1)$, or the half-open interval $[0,1)$ or
$(0,1]$. Simulating from $\mathrm{Unif}(0,1]$, what you typically get
is an IEEE floating point number. If you take it at face value, it is
a rational number, from a particular finite subset of
$\mathbb{Q}$. Among other things this set includes integers of some
bounded size. Your next arithmetic operation might well be (say)
$1/x$, and it would be inconvenient if $x=0$ has positive probability.

Note that mathematically there is *no difference* in "the uniform over
$(0,1)$" and "the uniform over $[0,1]$". They specify the *same*
cumulative distribution function.  So there is no difference in
sampling from this or that (because they are the same thing).

What is **meant** is a difference in the **sampling distribution**,
not in the underlying continuous distribution.  I believe it is
usually meant, and desired, that the sampling should never return a
(floating) number $x_0$ where the underlying density is zero.

In particular, by saying "sample from the uniform over $(0,1)$", we
mean "sample from that distribution *so that the samples are in
the interval* $(0,1)$".  Similar for closed and half-open intervals.  This is
a convenient mathematical fiction, or abuse of notation.

## Answer to Q2

Actual pseudorandom generators do take the endpoints into account.
For example, the Python [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random) says it will return a "random
floating point number in the range 0.0 <= X < 1.0", and that's what it
does. The [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_randommodule.c) is not that difficult: First it
generates a pseudorandom integer in range $0,\ldots,2^{53}-1 =
9007199254740991$. Then divides by $2^{53}$.  The precision has been
chosen so that the maximum possible value is a float strictly
smaller than $1.0$.  So it never returns $1.0$, not even with a small
probability.

If you want to simulate from $\mathrm{Unif}(0,1)$ with both endpoints
impossible, there are two simple solutions. One is to reject and
resample if the undesired value happens (which is rare). The other is
to sample the integer from $1,\dots,2^{53}-1$ in the first place.

Endpoints are usually the main concern here, and they are easily dealt
with.  Another typical endpoint case is sampling a positive waiting
time from $\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$.

Much less common would be isolated zeros in the density, such as $f(x)
= (3/2)x^2$ for $-1 < x < 1$.  If you don't want $x=0$ to ever happen
in your simulation, the obvious easy solution is rejection and
resampling in that rare case.  There are other solutions that avoid
resampling: you could first sample from the strictly positive part,
then flip the sign with probability $0.5$.

Note: A [related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68218/sample-from-continuous-uniform-distribution-with-open-interval) about the implementation has been asked
and answered in Cross Validated.